# Multi-page Dash app with synced dropdown menu not working

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm quite new to Plotly-Dash, and I'm currently struggling with the **multi-page-dropdown.py** example I found on the [Dash Recipes Github](https://github.com/plotly/dash-recipes/blob/master/multi-page-dropdown.py) because it is not working as I would expect.

I would like to have a multi-page app, with a dropdown menu on all pages that works as a filter on what is displayed on such pages; the dropdown selection should be persistent on all pages. The behaviour I'm looking for is displayed in the following GIF.

https://github.com/plotly/dash-recipes/blob/master/multi-page-dropdown-example.gif

When I run the recipe, however, I see an empty plot, when I open a new page.

My understanding of the callbacks that regulate the functioning of the code is that `update_graph` updates the plot based on the dropdown selection **or** when the URL changes (i.e., when a new page opens).

What I notice when I run the code provided in the recipe is that  the `update_graph` callback updates correctly the graph when the dropdown selection is changed, but it fails to update the graph on a new page, when I open it.

Please find below the code I'm running, for reference.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong and should be done differently?

Thanks in advance for your support!

```py
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, State, Output
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
    'y': [3, 2, 4, 1, 4, 5, 4, 3, 1],
    'group-1': ['/', '/exhibit-b', '/exhibit-c', '/', '/exhibit-b', '/exhibit-c', '/', '/exhibit-b', '/exhibit-c'],
    'group-2': ['LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'London', 'London', 'London', 'Montreal', 'Montreal', 'Montreal'],
})

app = dash.Dash()
app.scripts.config.serve_locally=True

# app.config.supress_callback_exceptions = True
app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True  

app.layout = html.Div([
    # This "header" will persist across pages
    html.H2('Multi Page Dash App'),


    # Each "page" will modify this element
    html.Div(id='content-container-part-1'),


    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='graph-control',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df['group-2'].unique()],
        value='LA'
    ),

    # Each "page" will modify this element
    html.Div(id='content-container-part-2'),

    # This Location component represents the URL bar
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False)
], className="container")

link_mapping = {
    '/': 'Exhibit A',
    '/exhibit-b': 'Exhibit B',
    '/exhibit-c': 'Exhibit C',
}

styles = {
    'link': {'padding': '20'}
}

@app.callback(
    Output('content-container-part-1', 'children'),
    [Input('url', 'pathname')])
def display_page(pathname):
    return html.Div([
        html.Div([
            html.Span(
                dcc.Link(link_mapping['/'], href="/") if pathname != '/' else 'Exhibit A',
                style=styles['link']
            ),

            html.Span(
                dcc.Link(link_mapping['/exhibit-b'], href="/exhibit-b") if pathname != '/exhibit-b' else 'Exhibit B',
                style=styles['link']
            ),

            html.Span(
                dcc.Link(link_mapping['/exhibit-c'], href="/exhibit-c") if pathname != '/exhibit-c' else 'Exhibit C',
                style=styles['link']
            )

        ]),

        dcc.Markdown('### {}'.format(link_mapping[pathname])),
    ])


@app.callback(
    Output('content-container-part-2', 'children'),
    [Input('url', 'pathname')])
def display_page(*args):
    return html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(
            id='graph',
        )
    ])


@app.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('graph-control', 'value'),
     Input('url', 'pathname')])
def update_graph(value, pathname):
    dff = df[(df['group-1'] == pathname) & (df['group-2'] == value)]
    return {
        'data': [{
            'x': dff.x,
            'y': dff.y,
            'type': 'bar'
        }],
        'layout': {
            'title': '{} in {}'.format(value, link_mapping[pathname])
        }
    }

app.css.append_css({"external_url": "https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css"})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be resolved by simply swapping the order of `display_page` and `update_graph` callbacks: the correct requires `update_graph` to come first in the code, and `display_page` to follow.

Now, my question is if it is possible to control the execution order of callbacks, to make sure everything is executed correctly?

Obviously, if anyone has more brilliant explanations or solutions, please come forward!

For reference, the piece should look like this.

```py
@app.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('graph-control', 'value'),
     Input('url', 'pathname')])
def update_graph(value, pathname):
    dff = df[(df['group-1'] == pathname) & (df['group-2'] == value)]
    return {
        'data': [{
            'x': dff.x,
            'y': dff.y,
            'type': 'bar'
        }],
        'layout': {
            'title': '{} in {}'.format(value, link_mapping[pathname])
        }
    }

@app.callback(
    Output('content-container-part-2', 'children'),
    [Input('url', 'pathname')])
def display_page(*args):
    return html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(
            id='graph',
        )
    ])
```